Хочу сделать свою игру на базе DOS игры "Поле Чудес с Листьевым" (Самара Диалог) 1992 года. Но есть один нюанс
Хочу создать свою Игру на базе DOS игры "Поле Чудес с Листьевым" (Самара Диалог) 1992 года. Хочу создать свои темы и вписать новые слова в базу.
Но есть один нюанс - при вскрытии библиотеки ресурсов, которая банально и просто запакована в текстовый файл Words.txt , я обнаружил что в ней очень странная кодировка - например "А" в одной ситуации может считаться как "А" а в другой может считаться как Б, В, Г, или любая другая буква.
Поэтому при попытке сделать частотный анализ библиотеки, для того чтобы влоб расшифровать код, получается абракадабра, и большинство слов игры все равно невозможно прочитать.
Вопрос в том, если кто бы смог помочь, подскажите, как нужно модифицировать частотный анализ для расшифровки ресурсов данной игры. Игра называется POLE Поле Чудес С Листьевым 1992 года авторы игры Самара-Диалог, но только не путать с куда более известной игрой Башурова Вадима 1993 года (игры абсолютно разные). ее можно скачать на сайте олд геймс ру (легко ищется в поиске) файл весит 90 кб, и в нем есть файл Words где собственно эта библиотека находится.Если кто поможет привести ее в читаемый вид и помочь написать код для того чтобы добавить свои слова, буду весьма премного благодарен)
код для декомпиляции подобной игры (изначально написан не мной для другой игры, но я его адаптировал уже для игры САБЖа).
Я хотел выложить файл с текстом который необходимо расшифровать, но здесь не нашел как выкладывать текстовые файлы. (он весит около 45 кб.кода, по этому отправить не могу) скачать файл с игрой можно по ссылке  или вот здесь
В нем есть папка WORDS.TXT где отдельным файлом находятся слова (разработчики старого кода даже заморочились над этим чтобы отдельно выписать библиотеку, за что им респект, но увы, старые кодировки которые написаны еще на старинном варианте паскаля, и поэтому современные проги не могут разобраться с ними без танцев с бубном.
сам код игры (который я еще не пытался дезассемблировать ввиду сложности) находится на файле WONDER.PCL
вот код для попытки декомпиляции файлов: если есть возможность, подскажите как модифицировать его для нормальной работы
:import os
import json
:
:with open('WORDS.TXT', 'rb') as f:
======================
data = f.read():
==========================
:def convert(rec):
=========================
wordlen = rec[0]:
=========================
word = rec[1: 1 + wordlen]:
====================================
word = bytearray(map(lambda x: x - 32, word)).decode('cp866'):
==========================
return word
================

:n = len(data) // 21:
==============================
print((n - 1) // 2, 'words'):
==============================
:words = {}:
==================
L = 21:
=================
csv = []:
=====================
for i in range(1, n, 2):
==========================
word_offset = i * L:
==============================
cat_offset = word_offset + L:
======================
word = convert(data[word_offset: word_offset + L]):
=======================
cat = convert(data[cat_offset: cat_offset + L]):
===================
cat_words = words.setdefault(cat, []):
==============================
cat_words.append(word):
==================================
csv.append(cat + ';' + word):
=================================
====

with open('words.json', 'wt') as f:
====================================
json.dump(words, f, sort_keys=True, indent=' '):
====================================
== with open('words.csv', 'wt') as f: f.write("\n".join(csv)):
================================

к сожалению Пайтон не совсем справляется со скриптами древнего Паскаля и не видит какие то еле заметные нюансы из за которых выходит абракадабра в тексте

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Что вы хотели сказать своим кодом? Он совершенно точно не похож на Паскаль, но и для Питона в нем, мягко говоря, есть непонятки.

Неисключено, что файл упакован. А может он и до упаковки не текстовым был.
Помню мой dr.web для dos мог определить упаковщик...

Файл сначала казался похожим на текстовый. Много переносов CR, LF, большинство байтов выше 0x7F, то есть вроде бы опять же текстовый с кириллицей. Но внезапно, ВСЕ байты выше 0x7F используются и почти равномерно. Что совсем непохоже на какую-то кодировку. Всё же или упаковано как-то странно (сохранены переносы строк и почти не используется остальной ASCII) или я не понимаю что это. Частотный анализ тут не поможет.

@4per Возможно, текст шифруется сдвигом на какую-то фразу циклически, с приводом обратно в тот же диапазон. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0 Там, кстати, написано и как его можно попытаться дешифровать.

@4per Что-то я попробовал хотя бы длину шифровальной фразы определить, но ничего внятного не выходит, частоты символов слишком равномерные (ну, кроме CR, LF), даже если брать каждый n-ный символ :/
